# How to merge two commits when none of them is last?

Tags: git, git-merge

Now my commit history look like this:

```
A - B - C - D - ... - LAST
```

I want to change it to this:

```
A - MERGED_B_C - D - ... - LAST
```

Is it possible to do that? If yes, how can I do that?

I tried to google, but most of solutions describe situation when one commit is last

Comment: You can, with git rebase. But look for other topics related ti git rebase, there are warnings you have to consider before you perform the operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
git rebase -i A
```

and then change C to "squash", which will do what you want. Note that this will change commit ID's for everything that follows, so there will be problems if those commits are published anywhere.

So the final look will be:

```
A - MERGED_B-C - D' ... - LAST'
```